# IN condition issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, conditional-statements

Can you explain why when I have an in condition the result is not returned in the same order as they are written?

I am trying to extract the column name from all_tab_columns and I want them to be retrieved in the same order as specified in the in condition.

Ex:

```
select * from all_tab_columns
where table_name='X'
and column_name in ('d','a','Z','e');
```

The output is:

column_name

a 
d 
e
Z

I would like the output to be in the same order as is specified in the `IN` condition.

Can you advise?

Comment: SQL data-sets are explicitly ***un-ordered***.  If you want the result-set to have a deterministic order, you ***must*** use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a CTE with the specific order of your choice, join it with `all_tab_columns` and order by CTE order.

```
WITH ord (rn, column_name)
     AS (SELECT 1, 'd' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'a' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Z' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'e' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT *
    FROM all_tab_columns t JOIN ORD o ON t.column_name = o.column_name
   WHERE table_name = 'X'
ORDER BY o.rn;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Oracle retrieves the result in Ascending order in `IN CLAUSE`. You need to explicitly mention the order in which you want to retrieve dataset in `Order by` Clause. Use this:

```
select * from all_tab_columns 
where table_name='X'
and column_name in  ('d','a','Z','e')
order by decode(column_name,'d',1,'a',2,'Z',3);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f09bdb/6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the filtering may vary in IN condition, and I will have to generate dinamically the position of each value.Can you advise? How I can do that?

Comment: @MathewLinton if the `IN` clause conditions are dynamic then how would you know what should be the order. Unlike the case you posted above, you explicitly mentioned, the way you wanted the output, If that is dynamic then you cannot even be able to decide on the ordering. In that case you have to choose either ASC or DESC.

Comment: What I was taking about was that i can have  ('d','a','Z','e') or i can have  ('d','a','Z','e', ...) and when we will use the decode how to add dinamically 1, 2... in order to keep the same order as added in IN condition

Comment: @MathewLinton For all the values in decode with numbering will always be in that order. I mean whatever be the case, after you put the above decode, always `d`,`a`,`z` be in order. Rest will be automatically sorted after these. So incase you wanted always to have these at the top, go with it. You cannot dynamically add such 1,2 ...else you would need to have a dynamic query and that will also not work incase you will not have any prior knowledge or order you want.

Comment: The rule is that the output to have the columns in the same order as they are added in the In condition specified by the user. Therefore I need something dynamically, otherwise will not work for all the cases.

Comment: @MathewLinton You can do that as well but that wouldnt be a good solution . You might have to think about dynamic SQL then.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to retrieve data from the database in some sorted order is to include an ORDER BY on your query. There is no substitute for ORDER BY.

Thanks.